como saber a que switchs y a que puerto está conectado un pc en la red

buen día, quiero crear un programa en  python para saber a que switch y a que puerto esta conectado un pc conociendo la mac de ese pc (ej: 00aa.eeff.1237 pc azul).
Para ilutrar la situación la explicación se hara con el diagrama de red adjunto.
actualmente lo que hago es ingresar al SWITCH CORE y buscar la mac que me han dado (ej: 00aa.eeff.1237 pc azul), el sw core me dice que que esa mac esta llegando por el puerto Te1/0/10 y como se puede ver en el diagrama a ese puerto esta conectado el switch 172.22.44.20.
me conecto al switch 172.22.44.20 y este me dice que esa mac pasa por el puerto Te1/0/2 y de nuevo se observa que a ese puerto esta conectado el switch 172.22.44.30
me conecto al switch 172.22.44.30 y este me dice que esa mac pasa por el puerto Te1/0/2 y de nuevo se observa que a ese puerto esta conectado el switch 172.22.44.40
me conecto al switch 172.22.44.40 y este me dice que esa mac pasa por el puerto Gi1/0/5 y de esta manera finalmente he encontrado el pc que estoy buscando.
NOTA: en cada switch hay una descripcion de los puertos que nos indica cual es el siguiente switch que esta conectado a los puertos Te1/0/x
SW-CORE# show interface description

Port        Status     Description
----------------------------------------------------------
Te1/0/1     up         SWITCH_44.20
Te1/0/2     down       SWITCH_44.X
Te1/0/3     down       SWITCH_44.X
Te1/0/4     up         SWITCH_44.22
Te1/0/5     up         SWITCH_44.25

lo que se desea es poder crear un programa que me ahorre todo este recorrido y me pueda dar la siguiente información del switch al que esta conectado el computador

ip del switch
puerto del switch donde se conecta el pc
vlan

NOTA: se dene tener en cuenta que en la red, los switch´s son de diferentes marcas y modelos, FS, Dell; allied Telesis
lo mas cercano que he encontrado es el software ldwin, sin embargo no es lo que busco (https://github.com/chall32/LDWin) y he mirado los módulos NETMIKO, PARAMIKO y SCAPY pero aun no doy con la posible solución
estoy intentandolo con lldp pero no he logrado mucho, por ejemplo, al hacer lldp la información que arroja un swich FS no es la misma que arroja uno de marca Dell
por ejemplo con lldp los switchs me regresan Chassis ID : 00:aa:ee:ff:12:34  pero al revisar la tabla ARP del CORE no aparece, es decir esa MAC no siempre es la que está asociada a la IP del switch que esta conectado a ese puerto.
con otros switch´s es mas facil ya que en la información que retorna el comando viene una linea como esta Management Address: IP: 172.22.44.22 y de ahí puedo sacar la ip
****** switch marca 1 *********
SW_CORE# show lldp neighbor interface Te1/0/1

Local Port Te1/0/1 has 1 neighbor(s)

Remote LLDP Information of port Te1/0/1
============================================================
Neighbor Index : 1
Chassis ID type: Mac address
Chassis ID     : 00:aa:ee:ff:12:34
Port ID type   : Interface Name
Port ID        : Te1/0/1

********* switchs marca 2 *******
SW_CORE# show lldp neighbor interface Te1/0/4


Local Port Te1/0/4 has 1 neighbor(s)

Remote LLDP Information of port Te1/0/4
============================================================
chassis id: 00aa.eeff.1238
port id: Te1/0/1
port description: Te1/0/1
system name: SW_BODEGA
system description: switch marca DRAGON modelo 1600
Management Address: IP: 172.22.44.22

en ocasiones el LLDP no me da la información suficiente para saber cual es la IP del switch siguiente

Puede que habilitando LLDP en los equipos te brinde el puntapie para lograrlo

@JULIAN lldp no me ha servido de mucho
